# Magento: Adding product-specific audio/video samples to the product page

Tags: magento

We've got a site where the customer sells physical, printed sheet music. They also have sample audio recordings of what the various compositions sound like, and they'd like to add these recordings to the product pages themselves. Among other things, the purpose of the recordings is to let a shopper play a recording of the composition so they know what they're buying.

The only way I can see to do this, without creating custom fields that we need to manually manage, is to create all the products as "Downloadable Products", and attaching the samples. The problem with doing a downloadable product, however, is that it actually has to have a downloadable component - my customer is not interested in selling, for example, PDFs of the sheet music. In our digital age you might think this silly, but they've already looked into doing this, and the end result is that sheet music is a little different than say, a book. Layout and formatting issues prevent sheet music from being a great candidate for digital distribution right now, since precise layout of the scales and notes is critical - i.e. the data is much more complex than text.

Any suggestions on how to pull this off? Are there extensions available that do this? I'd imagine an online store that sells physical CDs or vinyl wanting to have audio samples next to their products for the same reason.

Comment: Do you want them to be able to download the audio sample or just click play and hear it either through HTML5 or Flash? If just download, I agree with @Rafael below. Otherwise, a little custom work would be in order.

Comment: Just a preview. It turns out the "description" fields on any product take HTML <embed> and <script> tags. Implementing this was a simple as uploading the audio files, and pasting some HTML into the product description field.

Comment: Indeed. If you use the wysiwyg editor though it may filter out embed and script tags. Not sure if Magento does this but most other wysiwyg filter by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a much simpler solution, which I didn't realize existed:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/32647/

Basically, the "Description" and "Short Description" fields on a product accept raw HTML, including `<script>` tags, which allow you to easily embed, for example, a Flash-based audio/video player, or even a YouTube video via an `<embed>` tag.

[Tim Reynolds](https://stackoverflow.com/users/163557/tim-reynolds) also pointed out that, if you use the WYSIWYG editor, these tags may get automatically filtered out, so watch out for that.

Answer (score 1):

I think adapt Mage_Downloadable is not the best way. Once that customer need to order (without cost) the downloadable product to gain access to download, maybe useless.

I don't mind that add a file (or a link to a public) to an attribute is hard, have to be more easy than change downloadable products to work in this way.

I think you need a simplest way of this extension: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magemechanics/extension/3027/product-file-upload. I'm right?